# What do -S -cwd -r -j -l mean when running a python script?

Tags: python, bash, command

I'm trying to run a python script I got from a colleague. At the beginning it has the following lines:

```
#$ -S /usr/bin/python
#$ -cwd
#$ -r yes
#$ -j y
#$ -l h_rt=10:00:00
#$ -l arch=lx24-amd64
```

Apparently it's supposed to be "changed to my local environment". I tried googling, but I don't know what any of these commands mean. I assume it tells my shell some things, but I don't know what they mean in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They look like they are [qalter](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qalter.html) command parameters for submitting this as a job to the Sun Grid Engine:

> If  the first two characters of a script line
>        either match '#$' or are equal to the prefix string  defined
>        with  the  -C option described below, the line is parsed for
>        embedded command flags.

Here is an excerpt from the man:

```
-S [[hostname]:]pathname,...
      Specifies the interpreting shell for the job. 

-l resource=value,...
      Launch the job in a Sun Grid Engine queue  meeting  the
      given  resource  request  list.

-j y[es]|n[o]
      Specifies whether or not the standard error  stream  of
      the job is merged into the standard output stream.

 -r y[es]|n[o]
      Identifies the ability of a job to be rerun or not.  If
      the  value of -r is 'yes', the job will be rerun if the
      job was  aborted  without  leaving  a  consistent  exit
      state.

 -cwd 
      Execute the job from  the  current  working  directory.
```

Comment: Ahh, this makes sense, the script was run on a Sun Grid cluster. Thank-you very much.

Comment: NP- They only look familiar to me because I just so happen to be working with a client who uses it.